# $V \subseteq T_1 U$, and $V \subseteq T_2 U$, is $V \subseteq [\lambda T_1+ (1-\lambda) T_2] U$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

$U, V$ are two convex subsets of vector spaces. $T_1, T_2$ are linear operators. $0<\lambda<1$.

$V \subseteq T_1 U \implies \forall v, \exists u_1$ such that $v = T_1 u_1$.

$V \subseteq T_2 U \implies \forall v, \exists u_2$ such that $v = T_2 u_2$.

To prove $V \subseteq [\lambda T_1+ (1-\lambda) T_2] U$, we need to find a $u_3$ for every $v$ such that $v = [\lambda T_1+ (1-\lambda) T_2] u_3$. However, I failed to construct a $u_3$ using $u_1$ and $u_2$.

I am aware of the facts that U and V are convex. But it still bothers me how to use it. Actually, I sense that whether V is convex does not matter. But $U$ being convex is crucial. I have tried to use the condition that any linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$ belongs to U. But Once it is multiplied by the linear operator $[\lambda T_1+ (1-\lambda) T_2$], terms like $T_2 u_1$ and $T_1 u_2$ appear, which I do not think to belong to $V$ in general.

Comment: What have you tried? This problem has a pretty short solution.

Comment: @William Updated. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hint: you haven’t used the facts that $U$ and $V$ are convex.

Comment: @William I am aware of the facts that U and V are convex. But it still bothers me how to use it. Actually, I sense that whether V is convex does not matter. But $U$ being convex is crucial. I have tried to use the condition that any linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$ belongs to U. But Once it is multiplied by the linear operator, terms like $T_2 u_1$ and $T_1 u_2$ appear, which I do not think to belong to $V$ in general. Can you be more specific on how to use the convexity condition?

Comment: Both conditions are necessary, barring additional assumptions. I recommend you put more thought into it, and if it hasn’t been answered/you haven’t discovered the (very pretty) proof by tomorrow, I would be happy to give the solution.

Comment: @William Thanks for your help! I think I figured it out. I am not familiar with some basic concepts of linear operator algebra and Minkowski addition. Please let me know if it's wrong. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for William and others' generous help.

$[\lambda T_1 + (1-\lambda) T_2] U = \lambda T_1 U + (1-\lambda) T_2 U$

Because $V$ is convex, $\forall \lambda, V = \lambda V + (1-\lambda)V$.

$\lambda V \subseteq \lambda T_1U$ and $(1-\lambda) V \subseteq (1-\lambda) T_1U$,

$V = \lambda V + (1-\lambda)V \subseteq \lambda T_1 U + (1-\lambda) T_2 U$.